# How to show scrollbar at the bottom and make table height as auto?

Tags: html, css, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I have written the following css which is working as expected on my laptop. But when using a bigger monitor I see blank space after end of the table.

```
  .wrapper{
    width:auto;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

When I use `overflow :auto;` the vertical scrollbar is completely removed and to see the horizontal scrollbar I have to scroll all the way down

The `html` is as below:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table id="myTable" datatable="ng" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table table-striped table-bordered display nowrap
    table-sm row-border hover" width="100%">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="min-width: 120px">hostName</th>
        ...
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr style="text-align: left; word-break: break-all;">
        <td>value</td>
        ...
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

If I make `height: auto` then the horizontal scrollbar goes at the very bottom and not shown on page top and the vertical scrollbar is no more scrollable.

Comment: Need more info. What is your html structure? What is wrapper? Is the table inside of an element with the class wrapper? Is there any css on the table itself?

Comment: added `html` in question

Comment: Can you try switching to overflow auto?

Comment: When I use `overflow :auto;` the vertical scrollbar is completely removed and to see the horizontal scrollbar I have to scroll all the way down

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirements, you were seeing blank spaces because overflow scroll is always visible, with auto they're displayed only when needed. What else do you need? Can you post an image of the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "px" try to use relative unit for the table height like "vh" or "%"

Comment: what should be the `vh` value in our case?

Comment: thats upto you to decide which ever fits all screens. Try different values.

Comment: I have tried `wrapper{
    width:180vh;
    height: 60vh;
    overflow :auto;
  }`  Will it work fine on other screens, if it is working fine on my laptop?

Comment: you need to check that on different screens. Try to shrink and extend screen size and observe how it looks.

Comment: How to shrink and extend screen size on windows machine? Do you mean using `ctrl +` and `ctrl -`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it out providing 100% height in your `body` and `html` tags:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Check it out
https://jsfiddle.net/oyzsvbw4/1/